# print specific string result execution on python

Tags: python, string, printing, output, txt

i i only want to save specific print result of every execution of code on text file

i try with

```
if to,from_addr != '0x':
            print(To:,From:)
            os.system(f'echo {To:} {From:} >> output.txt')
```

but everytime fail, also I also want that every time a new result appears, a new line is added and not replace the later output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1650p.png)

i try with

```
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(f"To:" "From:" {to} {from_addr}", file=text_file)
```

Comment: `from` is a reserved word so I would not use that a variable name.  I have a hard time understanding what you are asking.  Maybe give us sample input (as text), and expected output?  Also, I can't tell if the above is incomplete snippets or if you haven't extract data from input into variables yet.

Comment: @AllanWind exactly, also `print` is not the function to write to a file, you need to used the file pointer `text_file` you defined when using context manager.

Comment: @Gameplay. `print` can write to a file if you specify `file=<handler>` as parameter. By default, `print` use the stdout handler. => `file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.` (documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` mode and fix f-strings:

```
to = 'destination'
from_addr = 'source'

# Use append mode
with open("Output.txt", "a") as text_file:
    if not (to.startswith('0x') or from_addr.startswith('0x')):
        print(f"To: {to}\nFrom: {from_addr}", file=text_file)
```

Comment: Does it do both, printing and saving?

Comment: @cards. It prints the output to `file` handler (saving)